# Need help identify host name

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, pika

I'm very new to rabbitmq, I installed rabbitmq-server on one EC2 instance, and want to create a consumer on another EC2 instance.

But I'm getting this error:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

That's the node status:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-147-xxx-xxx:~$ sudo rabbitmq-server restart
ERROR: node with name "rabbit" already running on "ip-10-147-xxx-xxx"

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: ['rabbit@ip-10-147-xxx-xxx']

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- ip-10-147-xxx-xxx: [{rabbit,46074},{rabbitmqprelaunch4603,51638}]

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqprelaunch4603@ip-10-147-xxx-xxx'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: Gsnt2qHd7wWDEOAOFby=
```

And that's the consumer code:

```
import pika

cred = pika.PlainCredentials('guest', 'guest')
conn_params = pika.ConnectionParameters('10-147-xxx-xxx', credentials=cred)
conn_broker = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)

conn_broker = pika.BlockingConnection(conn_params)
channel = conn_broker.channel()
channel.exchange_declare(exchange='hello-exchange', type='direct', passive=False, durable=True, auto_delete=False)

channel.queue_declare(queue='hello-queue')
channel.queue_bind(queue='hello-queue', exchange='hello-exchange', routing_key='hola')

def msg_consumer(channel, method, header, body):
    channel.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)
    if body == 'quit':
        channel.basic_cancel(consumer_tag='hello-consumer')
        channel.stop_consuming()
    else:
        print body

    return

channel.basic_consume(msg_consumer, queue='hello-queue', consumer_tag='hello-consumer')
channel.start_consuming()
```

Comment: You sure you opened up the ports in your Security Group. Also does this client work on the server where rabbit is installed.

Comment: Any progress on this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check that the security group allows you to use the rabbitMQ port, also it seems that you are not using Rabbit default's port (5672) so it should be in your connection parameters